# Event driven programming

Tags: programming, arduino-mega, threads, events

I have ran across a couple of different event libraries that are available on the AVR and Andruino but I am not sure which one is the best option. What I would like to do is design my program in a event driven style but not sure how to go about this.

I have a project that I need to keep lightweight but also in this program I have several actions that can be happening at any given time i.e. Digital Inputs being triggered and I need to run code whenever these events happen.

I found [the QP Framework](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/QP) that looked promising but I wanted to get some feedback from some others that might of used this type of library before and might be able to provide some examples and maybe some experiences.

Another site I found [here](http://blog.ardublock.com/2013/10/29/evaluating-of-event-driven-libraries-on-arduino/) and lists all sorts of different libs

Comment: [Cosa](https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa) has to be the most fully featured of them all that I know of. Amazingly powerful and filled with drivers for everything you can imagine.  It's a completely different way of programming the Arduino - you'll have to unlearn everything you know ;)

Comment: @Majenko I had asked about OOP Programming (http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17964/oop-vs-inline-with-arduino) does Cosa handle the problem with dynamically allocating memory?

Comment: It's pretty much all static objects.

Comment: @Andy Braham, if I may add to Majenko's statement, It's pretty much all static objects, **which is a good thing.**  As stated in the OOP thread, dynamic memory on small AVRs is not a good choice.  (It's something you have to un-learn.) Besides determinism, static binding also allows fantastic compile- and link-time optimizations.

Comment: Is the code that needs to be run interruptable?  How much latency can you tolerate?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at LMX by David Anderson [A Light-Weight Multi-Tasking Executive](http://www.geology.smu.edu/dpa-www/robo/LMX).

He has a very good set of videos on the code that he did for [Dallas Personal Robotics Group (DPRG)](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsGzeeBTraAts7lMQdfhqtA).

The specific videos for LMX are:

- [David Anderson on Robotics Software - part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRaosdrDrdA)
- [David Anderson on Robotics Software - part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jnrg4WAtxGQ)